# How to iterate over the data returned in the VM format in c# core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to iterate over the data that I am getting from my service function in c#. The aim is to iterate over the data received from the service function and then create an html format that can then be used to create a pdf file.
This is my controller function code where the result is being pulled from the service function:

```
var rv = await service.GetAccountInvoices(model);
```

And here the detail format of what `rv` is getting from the service:
[image]

The service function is working fine and is returning 10 items but I am just having trouble iterating over the result that is stored in the variable `rv`.

Here is the data type details of `rv` that is returned from service:

[image]

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Comment: Can you add the type of output from the service.GetAccountInvoices(model)?

Comment: use foreach loop to iterate over it?

Comment: @LeszekP I can't because that is not a normal array or object. That is a model.

Comment: `rv.ForEach(//Action<T> **dothings**)`

Comment: `foreach (var item in rv.Items)`?

Comment: @saurav.rox Can you please show us this model? The naive version I have in mind is to iterate over `rv.Items` if that's a publicly accessible member, but to give an exact answer, we need to see the `InvoiceDto` class.

Comment: @YongShun I used foreach later and it worked. Twisted my code a bit. I will post the answer soon here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I was able to do it. I was struggling to use foreach but had to do some research before using it in the response call

```
 foreach (var item in rv.Items)
 {
```